# Record music player audio while video recording ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, avaudiosession

I am recording video in my application with use of [this](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) code.Video recording is working fine no issues with that. My problem is when i am playing music in default music player and trying to record video in my app music player audio play getting stop. I don't want to stop music player audio. 
All popular application doing this.

I updated following code in PBJVision.m in this method - (id)init

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];

NSError *error;

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:2 error:&error];
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"error doing outputaudioportoverride - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

it is working for ios 7 but not working for ios 8.

Anyone having soultion for this problem ?

Comment: Hey Viral check below link. It worked perfectly for ios8.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7