# How to record video and maintain music playing in the background?

Tags: ios, audio, video, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a question similar to this. I have a custom camera/recorder that I made with AVFoundation and I was wondering how to keep the audio running from other apps while recording a video because right now it stops the audio (doesn't even pause it) and then records the video

If I am thinking correctly, could this be solved by adding something similar to this:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

Comment: Could there possibly be a another alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This fixed it.


[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work on mine. Where did you put this code?

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Code:**

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

OSStatus propertySetError = 0;

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty ( 
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,                         
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),                                      
    &audioRouteOverride                                               
); 
[session setActive:YES error:&error];
```