# AVCaptureSession with background Music in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

In my application I want to record a video with music playing in background. I have achieved this through AVCaptureSession and AVAudioSession.

After recording (through headset) my music file output will be a combination of the sound recorded through mic + the background music played through the speaker. But my issue is that the sound of the background music played through the speaker is very low on the final output music.

I have gone through [AVCaptureSession and background audio iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7)
and added the below code in my viewDidLoad, but with no change in volume.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```

How can I increase the volume of the background music in my final output?