# Combine recorded video and background music in iOS

Tags: ios, video, avcapturesession, avaudiosession

In my application I want to record a video with music playing in background. I have achieved this through `AVCaptureSession` and `AVAudioSession`.

After recording (through headset) my music output will only contain the recorded video sound. Is there any way to combine the music playback with the recorded video so that the final output will contain the music playback + recorded video with sound

I have gone through the following question : [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7) and added the below codes in my viewDidLoad but no change in volume.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```

But no change on the final result.

Comment: You want to merge an video and audio file?

Comment: My doubt is that is it possible to get a final video output with the sound captured through the headset mic + the sound played through the headset speaker without manually mixing them ?