# Background music cancelled when capturing audio in AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, xamarin, backgrounding

I would like background music to continue playing when I am inside my iOS app. However when ever I enter my app the background music is cancelled. I isolated the problem to the audio part of the AVCaptureSession:

```
var audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio);
var audioInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice(audioDevice);
captureSession.AddInput(audioInput);
```

I tried setting the AudioSession immediately after in two ways:

```
AudioSession.Initialize();
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.AmbientSound;
AudioSession.SetActive(true);
```

or like this:

```
AudioSession.Initialize();
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;
AudioSession.OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers = true;
AudioSession.SetActive(true);
```

But neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly creating an instance of the session object and setting MixWithOthers, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7)? I'm thinking the Xamarin equivalent would be something like

```
AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker);
```

Alternatively, as suggested in the link above, try setting the following in your AppDelegate:

```
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord;
AudioSession.AudioShouldDuck = true;
AudioSession.OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker = true;
```

...and then creating your AVCaptureSession like this:

```
AVCaptureSession session2 = new AVCaptureSession();
session2.AutomaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false;
```